# How to create "this" object in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of name's and id's. I have displayed it with ng-repeat property. I want to show the corresponding id's along with the name in 1 second on its click.

```
$scope.showFn = function() {
  $scope.showPopup = true;
  $timeout(function(){
    console.log("timeout");
    $scope.showPopup = false;
  }, 1000);
};
```

I have created a plunker 
 https://plnkr.co/edit/kvkgwp60Bxq2MrHrr5Rr?p=preview 

Now showing all the id's in a single click. Please help. 
Thanks.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/VUn28J6jp0j1sX6VuwDK?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="main">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <a href="#" ng-click="showFn(item.id)">{{item.name}}</a>
        <span ng-show="showPopup && item.id == shownId">{{item.id}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Controller will be like below:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('main', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.items = [{
      "name": "one",
      "id": "1"
    }, {
      "name": "two",
      "id": "2"
    }, {
      "name": "three",
      "id": "3"
    }, {
      "name": "four",
      "id": "4"
    }, {
      "name": "five",
      "id": "5"
    }, {
      "name": "six",
      "id": "6"
    }, {
      "name": "seven",
      "id": "7"
    }]

    $scope.showFn = function(Item) {
      $scope.shownId = Item;
      $scope.showPopup = true;
      $timeout(function() {
        console.log("timeout");
        $scope.showPopup = false;
      }, 1000);
    };

  });
```